# Is it a common practice to have similar package names?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

In case we have a web application and another back-end application that deals with database connectivity. Is it a common practice to have package with similar names across the two applications?

Comment: I would avoid that - use `com.mtleis.web` and `com.mtleis.thing` or something like that as a prefix. If you end up with the same package name in both that may be an indication that you should have a library to both.

Comment: Could you give us example of your packages' names? And if many apps access to databases, it wouldn't be silly that each app's source code possess some about a database package. But I do agree with @BoristheSpider with the fact you should avoid it as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

@mtleis, see this is exactly my point: this is an indication that I have a library to both package based on comment from @BoristheSpider

the story is not being told in the right way.

Basically, the kernel library is developed with Eclipse at a root package path of "com.mtleis" and in this workpsace only the kernel part of database ORM is implemented. The choice of Eclipse is due to SDK limitation from some dependent software.

However, because the final product is servlet based, so the ORM needs to be tested properly with a servlet shell implementation for alpha test. The test front is implemented in root package path of "com.mtleis" as well due to some enforced limitation imposed on class visibility. The servlet shell of "com.mtleis" is a Netbean workspace project

So basically, the kernel part from Eclipse is the legacy system library wrapped in one jar and servlet test front is merely consuming this jar but limited on class visibility. The only overlapping is the package path to avoid complexity of class visibility during testing.